# AngularJS Material - ng-checked on md-radio-button with ng-value as an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-material

I've looked around to see if anyone has answered this and it appears they have not.  I want to use an object rather than a string or integer as the value of the radio button.  Is this possible?  Doesn't seem so because I'm having trouble with the tags `md-radio-button` recognizing an object rather than string or integer value as having been selected.  I can see that it works after the page loads and I select something but I don't know how to check the radio button if the value already exists.  You can see a very simple demonstration here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZmjrLN

I've tried `class="md-checked"` to see if that works, it does not.  I've tried `ng-checked="selectedStatus.Name == status.Name"`, it doesn't work either.  In fact `ng-checked="true"` also does not work.

I would think `md-radio-button` could work with an object!

**--- EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION ---**

From an answer below, referencing the code from codepen, if I use the same object in `$scope.statuses` to populate `$scope.selectedStatus`, it indeed selects the correct radio button on load.  HOWEVER, in the real world `$scope.selectedStatus` is populated with the actual status from the server and `$scope.statuses` is also populated from that same call.  They are the same but 2 different objects.

In a nutshell, I still want to check off the correct one, even though the objects aren't exactly the same, they should be treated like they are, because they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing objects, ng-checked looks to see if checked is the same object or a reference and does not check the contend of the object. So to set the selected / checked radio button, make the value refer to the object. Here is an example of the Javascript updates for your codepen:

```
angular
  .module('BlankApp')
  .controller('AppController', function($scope) {
    $scope.statuses = [
      {id: 1, Name: 'Active'}, 
      {id: 2, Name: 'Dormant'}
    ];
    $scope.selectedStatus = $scope.statuses[0]; // reference the object directly
  });
```

Or if the value is set outside of the scope and we have to compare, then we can compare manually and then set the selectedStatus by finding the correct object and assigning it.

```
angular
.module('BlankApp')
.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.statuses = [
    {id: 1, Name: 'Active'}, 
    {id: 2, Name: 'Dormant'}
  ];
  $scope.selectedStatus = {id: 1, Name: 'Active'};

  // Find the index of the selected that matches on id
  let i = $scope.statuses.findIndex((val) => {
    return val.id = $scope.selectedStatus.id;
  }); 

  $scope.selectedStatus = $scope.statuses[i]
});
```

Comment: That does indeed work.  HOWEVER, the selectedStatus variable is populated with an object from the server.  Basically the `scope.statuses` is actually in a component that is resolved when a state is called and that state is populated with a call from the db.  `selectedStatus` is populated with the status from the same resolve call.  You see what I mean?  It's the same object but it's coming from the server.  I guess I could do something in the `$onInit` function to check for status being populated and use the id to repopulate it with the variable from the list but that seems like overkill

Comment: See if the above edits will work for you. Hmm, considering what you said, you mave have to place all that inside a $watch block or similar.